# (MSWord VBA) Add " symbol to search string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to get a simple macro to work in MS word. The macro is supposed find a definition in contracts. These are typically marked within quotes (e.g. "Definition"). Hence, I want to select a word that I want to search the definition for and execute a search for the selected term in quotes. The makro should then just jump to the definition. (I'll add a part later to jump back to the reading positon, but that part works fine).

However, for some reason, I can't get it to work reliably. I've gone through the code debugging it, but the MySearchTrim variable ends up just containing

> ""selectiontest

[This is what the variable content looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOxTK.png)

while I would need it to be

> "selectiontest"

I've tried it with inserting the quotes by adding the quotes through

> &"""

or through

> "([" & ChrW(8220) & "-" & ChrW(8221) & _
> "])" & MySearchTrim & "([" & ChrW(8220) & "-" & ChrW(8221) &"])"

but it only worked in 30% of the cases, which I find very confusing.

Can anyone help me spot the error?

Thanks!

```
Sub GehZuDefinition()

Dim MySearchterm
Dim MySearchTrim As String
Dim myWindow As Window
    
    MySearchterm = Selection.Text
    MySearchTrim = Chr(34) & Trim(MySearchterm) & Chr(34) ' trimming spaces after searchterm that are typically selected
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = MySearchTrim
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only searches for terms in plain quotes. And, in any event can be both simplified and made more efficient. For example:

```
Sub GehZuDefinition()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = """" & Trim(Selection.Text) & """"
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Replacement.Highlight = True
  .Format = True
  .Forward = True
  .MatchCase = True
  .MatchSoundsLike = False
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Since you don't say what you want to do with the found terms, the above code simply highlights them in green.

Comment: Unfortunately, your version also does not work. I've created a document with just
"Test"
Test
When I select the unquoted term and run the macro, nothing happens. When debugging it, it seems that it searches for ""Test and not "Test"

Comment: That simply is not correct. Using your example, the code I posted would search for "Test". You can prove that for yourself with nothing more complicated than MsgBox """" & Trim(Selection.Text) & """"

Comment: I understand that it does not make sense. I ran your code in step mode and made a screenshot of the content of .Text which is used for the search. Ive added the screenshot to my question. The text that was selected is simply the word test without quotes.

Maybe it has something to do with the selection.

Comment: Clearly, then, there is something you haven't told us. Are you using an RTL language setting, or Track Changes, for example? Moreover, the code I posted only applies highlighting - it doesn't change any content - so I can't see how you could possibly get the result you posted with that code.

Comment: You may have solved my comment with your comment. I've deactivated track changes and it seems to be related to that. I still have to verify with a couple of test documents but thanks a lot. I did not know that track changes could have that effect.
That also explains why it worked sometimes.